# Permissions of pyfilesystem when removing files

Tags: python

I am confused about the permission of pyfilesystem operation, look at the following code:

```
from fs.osfs import OSFS

a = OSFS('test')
a.remove('new1')
a.remove('new2')
```

and the ownership of these two files is:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 monkey monkey    0  1月 14 15:34 new1   
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0  1月 14 15:34 new2
```

The result is that I can remove `new2` with `"root, root"` ownership, besides, when I use pyfilesystem to create a file, the ownership is `"monkey, monkey"`. Can anyone can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a issue on pyfilesystem.
This is a normal phenomenon in linux.

When you remove a file, the permission of the enclosing directory rather than the one of the removed file matters.

In this case, you maybe have the write permission of the directory, so you can remove `new2` file.

Therefore, you can also use `rm new2` to remove `new2` in your bash.

Comment: I have tested this on Ubuntu,  and that is absolutely right!  A user who own a directory can **delete**  files under the directory even the files  with `root,root` ownership.